# High traffic windows server configuration

Tags: windows-server-2008, raid, traffic

I'm running a large website with 400.000+ visitors a day and currently setting up a new server environment (one web, and one db server).

I would love to hear how Jeff and Joel has setup their Web and Db Server configuration for high traffic.

For instance:

- I also have a RAID 10 on my db server - should I setup automated
  defragmentation?
- How does your app pool advanced settings look like - what queue
  length?
- Have you changed the MaxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU setting?
- Do you have an extra drive dedicated to paging?

Any info you can give is much appreciated.

Comment: If you take a look at the [Server Fault blog](http://blog.serverfault.com/), that contains some really good information on how the Stack Exchange network is set up in terms of hardware and software. Also, they talk about scalability problems they've had in the past too, along with some solutions.